# Please Move the CW Checkbox

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-wiki

I've seen a couple people complain that it's not easily visible when authoring a new question. Your eyes naturally wonder down the left-side of the page and miss the checkbox on the right that washes right into the background of the site.

Could this be moved down near the <kbd>Ask Your Question</kbd> button instead, and maybe be given slightly more contrast to make it pop off of the background a bit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in its current location by design and very VERY much intentionally.

(also note that this checkbox is not shown at all to brand new users, because we don't expect them to understand what it is, etc. If you want to see that, log out, then go to the /ask page)

Answer (score 5):

I would almost rather see the checkbox moved to the top rather than further to the bottom. That way it would definitely catch my attention more.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be more useful if it could be a **user setting** and not for each question.

Comment: Disagree completely.

Comment: I agree with TheTXI on this one.

Comment: I think this is a decision that needs to be made for each question asked.